# From a financial standpoint, how much more can I expect to earn after my degree?

Tags: mathematics, engineering, early-career

While certainly there is value to learning something you are passionate about, one might also have to consider the finnacial responsibilities after college. Thankfully for me, what I am passionate about is also what I can expect to make a decent career out of.

I am entering college as a mechanical engineering student, however I feel like I would very much like to pursue a double major, the second degree being in math. While what drives me to this is my interest and passion in the subject (Ive always been a fan of numbers), I can't help but pause to consider if the extra time and money spent is practical. In short, how much more can I reasonably expect to make with a bachelor's degree in math and in mechanical engineering, upon graduation?

Comment: You can end up in a fast food place serving or an insurance company calculating risk or an engineering design co - salary for the last two is more that the first one - but who knows where you will be...

Comment: 1) any question about salaries can be answered only if we know the country/ region and specific industry you intend to work, 2) even so, it is most probably not an academia related question, but industry, so you get better answers from them, 3) I don’t think a double major directly help you to have higher salary. The value is maybe on long term providing you flexibility in career choices, and letting you to carve your own niches. My prediction would be if you just work as an average engineer, you will not get more salary.

Comment: Add further details on background and country, and degree specifics. In my country, a graduate mathematician typically  becomes a teacher earning less than 1,000 usd a month.

Comment: Don’t forget about the opportunity cost of being in school longer versus earning money already working.

Comment: Don't expect an automatic higher salary due to a degree. Ask the starving computational chemists how their very useful capabilities pay... - A degree can open the doors to higher pay, but there is no guarantee. As others have said, study what you enjoy (and if you enjoy something applied, this may be beneficial as it will be easier to find work for applied sciences).

Comment: @Scientist That's a lot of money for being a teacher.

Comment: There is no chart. It boils down to how well you can negotiate and how well you can apply yourself to a given need. There are people with Master's degrees that cannot muster more than a colleague with an associates degree in the same field. The one with the master's usually studied under the false premise of better compensation rather than because they enjoyed their chosen field.

Comment: Engineering already contains plenty math. Many pure engineering courses are also basically just applied math. If yet more math courses were valuable to engineering, they would offer them in their own curricula. So the short answer would be the additional math probably won't add anything to your career, other than helping keep you sane and interested in your studies.

Comment: @corey979 mind I said less than 1000, to fit almost all cases, accommodating for rates fluctuations . Most will be way less. And workload can be high, plus bad students. Nobody wants to be a teacher here...

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close and have voted to reopen.  A question of whether a dual major will likely lead to a higher salary does not depend on personal preferences or values or the regulations at the school you go to.  It's a simple question with an actual answer.  Is it possible those voting to close simply lack experience in industry that causes them to think this is difficult to answer?

Comment: Agree with Nicole Hamilton and voting to reopen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pursue the dual major because it interests you and this is your opportunity to do  it, not because you expect a higher salary, because the higher salary probably won't happen.

I spent a long career in industry in engineering before coming out of retirement to teach a few years ago.  In my experience, hiring managers generally don't care that someone was a dual major.  Part of this may be a reflection of the fact that managers tend to hire people who "look like them".  Not very many managers were dual majors, so they don't value it.  But there's a practicality to it as well:  If they're hiring you to be an engineer, it's probably because you are an engineer, not because you're also a mathematician.

What hiring managers do value is the master's degree.  Again, this may be in part because so many hiring managers have master's degrees (which many of them may have earned part-time while working).  Hiring managers tend to have master's degrees, so they like to hire people with master's degrees, and they will pay more to get them.

If your concern is best financial return on any additional effort beyond what it takes to get a bachelor's degree, I recommend going for the master's over the dual major.  Many universities have programs that allow students to go straight through to their master's, double-counting some of their credits and earning both degrees with just one more year of coursework only, no thesis required.  For example, here at University of Michigan in computer science, where I teach, it's  called SUGS (Sequential Undergraduate/Graduate Studies); to be admitted to the program you need to be a junior or a senior with a 3.6 GPA.  Your school probably has a similar program.

If your objective is a career in industry and you're concerned about "bang for the buck", the master's is the way to go.

Comment: +1 but I'll add that with a dual major, it's possible the OP ends up working in a job that uses his math degree instead of engineering.

Comment: @Allure True. But most jobs that use a Bachelor's degree in math pay less than those that use a Bachelor's degree in mechanical engineering (at least in the U.S.) Engineering and Comp Sci majors have, by far, the highest starting salaries for graduates with a Bachelor's degree in the U.S.

Answer (score 5):

Expecting a difference in salary is not reasonable. It just wont be that simple. Your expectations will not be falsifiable.

You can expect to have more options. That is where the value here lies. You will definitely have more options to choose from, one of those options could include a higher salary, but also working environment, residency location, etc.

Having more options is always desirable.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in mathematics, but are also trying to maximise your future earnings, I would recommend a minor in math, then getting an MS in mechanical engineering.

A dual major won't earn you any more on its own. It might open additional opportunities, but since an undergraduate degree in pure mathematics likely will present less opportunities than an undergraduate degree in mech engineering, the benefit there is small. (but those additional math opportunities are something you might want to keep in mind if that is what you want to pursue, but at that point, why get a degree in mech eng?)

A masters degree will earn you more in engineering though. I will give you an example. The first company I worked for, a big bay area tech company that everyone has heard of, had this as their hiring policy: $x for new grads with a BS, $x+10k for new grads with an MS.

A minor in math would look good an a graduate application. A graduate degree in ME should earn you more money. So that path seems to check all the boxes you are looking for.

Comment: "$x for new grads with a BS, $x+10k for new grads with an MS." remember that you have ~2 years of lost income at ~$100k to get your masters... that means it takes 20 years to earn back the masters if the pay differential holds (hint, it doesn't)

Answer (score 3):

*I'm in IT, so take my opinionated answer with a grain of salt. This may seem like a rant, but I have heard the sentiment from colleagues, often.*

> In short, how much more can I reasonably expect to make with a bachelor's degree in math and in mechanical engineering, upon graduation?

Frankly: if you are looking at two *bachelor* degrees, relatively unrelated, then I, as a hiring manager, could not care less. Yes, I would see that you are a good learner, but I assume that the mechanical engineering covers all the maths needed, thus the additional maths bachelor only reinforces the fact that you like (and can do) maths. I would assume that I have to teach you a lot if not most real-world techniques on the job anyways.

It would be a bit different if you had two masters. For a master's degree, you not only need to get the deeper education, but also that much more personal effort. I.e., you're not only learning what is pushed your way, but writing a lot more stuff yourself, and your marks have much more meaning.

In my industry (IT/CS),  I am noticing a trend for young students to skip their masters, and end their academic career with the bachelor. I am very unhappy about this. Yes, at least in my country the unis don't really offer that much real life experience during the masters, but I'd never, ever underestimate the value of learning. Even if it's just advanced concepts. Or time spent on uni projects with significant resources available (depending on your uni of course) but without the stakeholder pressure of getting a usable product (in other words: *research*).

When I was little, we did not have the bachelor/master system in technical studies in my country; instead, there was a "Vordiplom" after 4-6 semesters, and then the "Diplom" after 8-12 or so semesters; the Diplom being somewhat comparable to the master's degree. My point is that the "Vordiplom" was worth *nothing* at the job market, at all. On the contrary, it signified that you aborted your studies before getting a real degree, and was a real bummer that you'd need to really explain in the interview.

I may be old-fashioned, and I know that reality has moved on, but the bachelor degree seems a little bit like that to me as well. Yes, those people *have* studied a topic for a few years, and they *have* their degree, but they chose to do the absolute minimum. Why? If they are interested in the topic, why would they not go on? Especially if they then had the time to do *two* of them?

Comment: +1  You've nicely described how a hiring manager might think about the matter, in agreement with my own observations.

Comment: Good answer especially from a German perspective, where students used to earn Masters-equivalent degrees per default before 'Bologna' introduced the BA/MA distinction. Now HR often (and perhaps rightfully) perceives the BA as a half-way degree.

Comment: From the OP's other questions, they're in the US. Although the OP's university may be different, in the US there is a difference between a *double major* and a *double degree*. If the OP is taking two courses that would normally end up both BSes (or BAs), that's a *double major* and it is in fact only one degree. If the programs are BA/BS, then that's a *double degree* and they do earn two degrees. From the question, it's likely that they will end up with a single bachelor's degree in mech e and math.

Comment: Another thing that may be a cultural difference here: Your grades ('marks') in a Master's (or Ph.D.) program in the U.S. mean essentially nothing. It's assumed that you will have all As or Bs in a graduate program here (at least in science and engineering.) At my university, 2 Cs was automatic expulsion from a graduate program. And 1 C was enough to have a long talk with your adviser. Your undergraduate GPA typically has more meaning than your graduate GPA here. Graduate degrees are valued, but the GPAs are mostly ignored.

Comment: This answer doesn't reflect how bachelor's and master's degrees are usually perceived in the US to the extent that I'm familiar with it. I think it's uncommon that anyone would consider a bachelor's degree holder to have "aborted their studies before getting a real degree"; instead, most people consider the bachelor's degree the completion of a full course of study. In terms of the system of your youth, a bachelor's degree is viewed somewhat like the Diplom and an associate's degree might be viewed similar to the Vordiplom, though somewhat more useful in the job market.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on a great number of things. So it may be possible to get a difference in mean income, though that would not be easy as we are dealing with relatively small groups. However, the variance tends to be very large for such estimates (I am not talking about statistical significance, just the raw variance). So a realistic estimate of the benefit of adding a second math degree would be somewhere between minus a lot and plus a lot, which is just another way of saying "that is unknowable without a working crystal ball".

Comment: Nations normally keep statistics on this and they are readily available to the interested. But statistics don't apply to individuals, only to populations.

Comment: @Buffy nations can ask that information in censuses or large survey, but very few nations can extract that information from their registers (the Nordic countries are a notable exception). Moreover, the OP asked about two very specific groups: those with a mechanical engineering degree and those with a mechanical engineering and  math degree. Often the field of study is not asked at that level of detail, and when it is the number of respondents in the last category is in all likelihood way too small to make reliable statements. So that is a lot harder than it looks.

Answer (score 2):

I used to employ 100s of graduates in the UK in a relatively high paying profession for which undergraduate degrees are available. When looking at candidates for employment I used to bear the following points in mind:

1. A bachelor's degree on its own is not normally a qualification to do anything: at best it provides some evidence of work ethic and of intellectual interests;
2. Further, in a way, any particular formal qualification tells only part of the story as to why its holder should be employed in an organisation. My staff were not exchangeable units of qualified people, but individuals who brought all sorts of skills over and above their technical qualifications;
3. I was slightly suspicious of candidates who had specialised too early. I wanted to see evidence of intellectual flexibility and that could be harder to see in a very specialised young person;
4. I was looking most of all for candidates who showed promise: capable of absorbing the further professional training they would need and then being brilliant;
   So, if the someone like the OP had turned up for a job with me with a dual major in mathematics and engineering, I would have been slightly more interested than if they had turned up with just one or the other degree, but the crucial issue is not what they did in the past but what can they do in the future.

So should the OP do a dual major or not? The answer depends on how he wishes to present him or herself to the world of work: how does the degree fit in with the intended career path.

Answer (score 0):

As part of my teaching studies I practiced at a university of applied sciences (ammattikorkeakoulu), an institute which trains engineers and other professionals mostly up to bachelor level, and offers no PhD studies. I talked to people who teached mostly electric engineering and the discipline where one learns how to construct houses and bridges etc. (It presumably has a specific name in English, which I do not remember off the top of my head.)

One long-time math teacher told me, that one thing companies look for in graduates or trainees is their mathematics grades, especially in advanced math courses, because these tell how challenging tasks they can set to the workers.

Supposing this second-hand knowledge from *mathematics* teachers is true (there is certainly motivation for bias), extra studies in mathematics might pay off as higher employability and more demanding positions. I cannot estimate any effect on wages.

Comment: Civil engineer, or maybe structural engineer.

Answer (score 0):

You will acquire more debt and as you make more you will spend more. Start this journey and you'll learn why 80% of the money in America is on credit. Good luck and stay positive on this depressing road to nothing.

Comment: You will not necessarily gain more debt for double majoring.  It all depends on how many hours you are willing to take per semester, and how many the school will let you take as a full time student.

Comment: "as you make more you will spend more".. huh you mean such as having a nicer home and vacation? The very thought is depressing indeed.